# How to get contents on BindPopup

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to get marker's .bindPopup content on click event so I can save it to localStorage. But it is not working properly for each marker.

```
 L.marker([76.920614, -60.117188])
 .addTo(map)
 .bindPopup('<div><span class="claimed">DATA 1</span></div>')
 .on('click', groupClick);

 L.marker([77.841848, -31.289063])
 .addTo(map)
 .bindPopup('<div><span class="claimed">DATA 2/span></div>')
 .on('click', groupClick)

 function groupClick(event) {
   var a = document.querySelector('.claimed').innerHTML;
   console.log(a);
 }
```

it would work on first click but on the second click on different marker, it will take the data from the first marker that i clicked instead of the second marker. In this case i have to click somewhere else on the map or click the popup close button first before i can click on the next marker to properly get the data. is there any fix on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM:**
you are selecting in your function **only the first appearance** of the class (not the clicked ones child) at

```
 var a = document.querySelector('.claimed').innerHTML;
```

**SOLUTION 1 (NOT RECOMMENDED):**
You should use the **this** keyword, and the **getPopup()** and **getContent()** methods instead, your function should look something like:

```
function groupClick(event) {
   var a = this.getPopup().getContent();
   console.log(a);
}
```

This way you'll get the escaped html, so a much better and proper way is...

**SOLUTION 2 (RECOMMENDED):** if you store the necessary data in the markers options (instead of storing and getting html from popup), like this:

```
 L.marker([40, 12], {data: 1, datastring: 'first'})
   .addTo(map)
   .bindPopup('ONE')
   .on('click', groupClick);
```

Then you can access this options in your function this way:

```
function groupClick(event) {
   var a = this.options.data + ' ' + this.options.datastring;
   alert(a);
 }
```

A [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dominagy/ku59y2qc/) again.

**EDIT:** I have found a workaround for the desired logic. But still, you need to link the marker and its popup content, because:
***Popup content is not a node in the DOM, so you cannot access it before it is opened with a user click.***

So in my solution i store a simple integer in the marker options ***(divId: int)***, which is the unique id of the marker. In the popup content, the radio inputs have the same id concatenated with the desired string (<input type="radio" id="Item-10-0" ***name="Item-10"*** value="0" checked="">).

```
L.marker([40, 32], {
     divId: 10
   })
   .addTo(map)
   .bindPopup('<div id="2div" class="popup-todo"><input type="radio" id="Item-10-0" name="Item-10" value="0" checked=""><label for="Item-10-0">Claimed</label><input type="radio" id="Item-10-1" name="Item-10" value="1"><label for="Item-10-1">Unclaimed</label></div>')
   .on('click', groupClick);
```

If the user clicks, the new node is already accessible, so you can select it and use its id and value.

```
function groupClick(event) {
    var a = document.querySelector('input[name=Item-'+this.options.divId+']');
    document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = a.id + ' ' + a.value;
 }
```

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dominagy/ngym5hxq/).

Comment: ok, i have been working on the first solution you gave and still a lot to learn in javascript. now i understand about queryselection. but how about if i want to get the html id, name, and value inside popup.. something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/aohfnms8/

Comment: on the radio button i want to save which id the user selected

Comment: Check the edit, i think the rest of it (localStorage store and retrieve on reload) you can implement, right?

Comment: yeah about that, can u give some basic code for localStorage on how to save what the user selected and load it when the page refreshed? for store and retrieve the localstorage i might have ideas but not really on implementing it on the html code when the .bindPopup is clicked

Comment: use `localStorage.setItem(a.id, a.value);` to set the item, and `localStorage.getItem(a.id);` to retrieve it. Check MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage).

Comment: ok, this mean i have to fire an onlick event for each radio button right? and use the localStorage code you gave?

Comment: Before you add the popup content, you have to check if something was already set and stored in localStorage. If so, you have to render the appropriate radio as "checked". `if(localStorage.getItem(a.id)){ var customPopupContent='...'; marker.bindPopup(customPopupContent);}` And yes, add the event listener to it to be able to check if its value changes.

Comment: thanks you so much i was able to save the selected input using your workaround with divId.

Comment: also how can i select the correct marker using divId? im stuck marker.bindPopup

Comment: You can use the `eachLayer()` method, more [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-eachlayer). Using eachLayer you can iterate through markers (layers) and chack if its option (divId) matches with your input. Something like: `map.eachLayer(function(layer){if('Item-'+layer.options.divId == a.id){ //do something here... }});`

Comment: could you check this https://jsfiddle.net/a3opk7wt/

Comment: nevermind, i manage to make it work now! really thanks alot!