# Solve: how to pass marker options into .bindPopup?

Tags: leaflet

So I have these markers with unique option values and I wanted to pass the markers option value to its .bindpopup I don't know if this is possible but here is my code and what i want to achieve.

```
var m8 = L.marker([30, 52], {
     divId: 8
   })
   .addTo(map)
   .bindPopup('Item-8 <div class="popup-todo"><input type="radio" id="Item-8-0" name="Item-8"     value="claimed"><label for="Item-8-0">Claimed</label><input type="radio" id="Item-8-1" name="Item-8"     value="unclaimed" checked=""><label for="Item-8-1">Unclaimed</label></div>')
   .on('click', groupClick);

var m8 = L.marker([40, 12], {
     divId: 9
   })
   .addTo(map)
   .bindPopup('Item-9 <div class="popup-todo"><input type="radio" id="Item-9-0" name="Item-9"     value="claimed"><label for="Item-9-0">Claimed</label><input type="radio" id="Item-9-1" name="Item-9"     value="unclaimed" checked=""><label for="Item-9-1">Unclaimed</label></div>')
   .on('click', groupClick);
```

and this is what i wanted to achieve

```
L.marker([30, 52], {
     divId: 8
   })
   .addTo(map)
   .bindPopup('<span id=##marker divId values here##>...</span>')
   .on('click', groupClick);

L.marker([40, 12], {
     divId: 9
   })
   .addTo(map)
   .bindPopup('<span id=##marker divId values here##>...</span>')
   .on('click', groupClick);
```

or is there any workaround that i can setup a default popup and use it with all markers combined with its divId option?

something like this

```
var defaultpop = '<span id="## divId value of current marker here ##"></span>'

L.marker([40, 12], {
         divId: 9
       })
       .addTo(map)
       .bindPopup('content from defaultpop')
       .on('click', groupClick);
```

**Solution i made so far**

```
L.marker([40, 32], {
     divId: 1
   })
   .addTo(map)
   .bindPopup('')
   .on('click', groupClick);

L.marker([10, 32], {
     divId: 2
   })
   .addTo(map)
   .bindPopup('')
   .on('click', groupClick);

function groupClick(event) {
var e = +this.options.divId;
this.bindPopup('<span class="'+e+'">LINK HERE</span><br     />###Longasshtmlcodehere##').openPopup()
}
```

this is exactly what I'm looking for now, now I can add more markers

Comment: This is done with string concatenation (or template strings), but I smell a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. What's the rationale for having some `divId` in the marker at all?

Comment: i needed to get the popup html value and id and have to use a code like this `var b = document.querySelector('input[name=Item-'+this.options.divId+']').value;` a solution from earlier problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67007066/how-to-get-contents-on-bindpopup

Comment: `var b = document.querySelector('.leaflet-popup input').value;`.

Comment: my code are working fine now but i think it can still be improve, i will be having hundreds of marker and it would be a lot of code if i put all bindpopup content on each marker

Comment: Loop through your markers.

Comment: yes got an idea using layer.bindPopup